# Bootstrap: How to stack two columns on top of two other columns on small screens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `form` layout with 4 columns that stacks on small or xs screens with `100% width`.

Is there a way to only stack 2 columns on top of the other two on small or xs?

Ideally, I'd like to show Column 1 and Column 2 in a row and Column 3 and Column 4 on the row below it on xs/small but all in the same row on medium/large.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form role="search" method="GET" action="/search/">
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    <label for="first-name">Column 1:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Column 1" name="fist_name" id="first_name" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    <label for="last-name">Column 2:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Column 2" name="last_name" id="title-search" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    <label for="city-search">Column 3:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Column 3" name="city" id="city-search" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm  col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    <label for="city-search">Column 4:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Column 4" name="state" id="state-search" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bayman/09xfkj1w/1/)

Ideal layout on small screen:

[image: crop photo]

Comment: add `col-xs-6` ..and RTFM ;) http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add class for extra small devices `XS` in this case `col-xs-6`

Take a look at [Boostrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) to know which class to use in each breakpoint

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form role="search" method="GET" action="/search/">
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    <label for="first-name">Column 1:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Column 1" name="fist_name" id="first_name" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    <label for="last-name">Column 2:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Column 2" name="last_name" id="title-search" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    <label for="city-search">Column 3:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Column 3" name="city" id="city-search" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm  col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
    <label for="city-search">Column 4:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Column 4" name="state" id="state-search" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these classes for the four `<div>`: `form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-3`.

Comment: don't need to repeat the `sm-6` when having the `xs-6`, and if OP has `sm-3` it doesn't need to change that to add `md-3`, because bootstrap is mobile first approach, so this answer doesn't make sense

Comment: Did that for clarification to the OP who didn't know about extra small screens. But yes you're right.

Comment: That's not clarification, it more misleading to me

Comment: You're not the OP though. And it is not misleading because it suggests the coder has to think about small and extra-small screens separately. Since you just suggested replacing `sm` with `xs`, it is misleading because it could be misinterpreted that `sm` is incorrect ... when in fact it is not incorrect to use `sm` for wanting a particular small screen layout.

Comment: OP wanted to stacked 2 columns in extra small devices, and keep the 4 as it were, so yes just adding `xs-6` was the answer, adding `sm-6` was meaningless (as I mentioned in my first comment) and if OP had already the `sm-3` then why in first place change that to `6` just to add the `md-3` when the `sm-3` was doing what was suppose to do? Ya I'm not the OP but  we need to interpreter what OP **really** wants